# Want to display the child terms of a two parents

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, taxonomy-terms

I want to display child terms of two specific parents with ID 36 and 37
I use this function

```
$categories = get_term_children(array(37,36),'product_cat');
```

but it doesn't work for an array :/
can anyone help me please
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to call `get_term_children` twice, once with each child

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas for your quick response , I can understand that there is no query that can display all of subcategories of multiple parent giving .
Thank you , your solution works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call get_term_children twice, once with each child .
The new code :

```
    $categories1 = get_term_children( 36, 'product_cat' );
    $categories2 = get_term_children( 37, 'product_cat' );
```

Resp from @chrisHaas